# PyCharm 5 ImportError

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I have a Python 2.7 file, which I am editing in PyCharm 5.0, and which depends on the library `libcudart.so.7.5`. This file is located at `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib` on my machine. To add this library directory to PyCharm, I `File->Settings->Project Interpreter`, then clicked on the cog wheel, then on `More`, and then on the selected `python2.7` interpreter, I clicked on `Show paths for the selected interpreter`. From here, I added `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib` to the list of interpreter paths.

However, when I run my Python file from within PyCharm, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But if I run it from the terminal, it runs fine. In my `.bashrc` file, I have the following line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

So why is this working through my terminal, but not through PyCharm?

Comment: .bashrc is for the shell, if you started pycharm from there it would work, you need to set it globally

Comment: Yes I understand this, but what I am wondering is why the settings I made in PyCharm do not work...

Answer (score 1):

add it into the `.profile` instead of `.bashrc` because the `.bashrc` is only applicable when you open a terminal so only work on the current terminal window the `.profile` execute when you login into the system so the env variables is setted for all the system not only for the current terminal

Comment: I have tried this, and running from PyCharm still does not work. Moreover, the main issue is that setting the library directory in PyCharm does not allow the library to be found, even when I run PyCharm from the terminal or set the directory in `.profile` as you suggested.